# Calibre not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, calibre

I tried to install calibre in Ubuntu 20.04 and it won't launch.
I followed the instructions from another question ([Calibre No Longer Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285431/calibre-no-longer-working?r=SearchResults)) but it didn't work.
This is how I installed (version 5.20.0):

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

I'm getting this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you explicitly need or want version 5? I see on the Ubuntu package list that the latest packaged version for 20.04 is 4.99.4 see here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=calibre&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all If that version is good enough you could try installing that version (from installer script or from Ubuntu app store). It may be that version 5 is not compatible with 20.04 due to the reasons highlighted in your link.

Comment: No, I don't care about the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=333503) might solve your issue. Quoting from [Calibre - Download for Linux page](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) -

> If you get an error Could not load the Qt platform plugin xcb you are missing some needed X11-XCB libraries, such as libxcb-xinerama0, for details see here

Comment: That worked perfectly!

Comment: March 2022 and I still got this issue in Ubuntu 21.10. Running "sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0" fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problems on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (focal) install.
Solved it by doing the following:

1. Installed the latest Calibre version (5.32) using:

   ```
   wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
   ```
2. Installed the `xcb` library using:

   ```
   apt install libxcb-xinerama0
   ```

No problems any longer after that. Many thanks to all for the hints.